# Mobile ignoring link styles, but shrunk desktop showing fine

Tags: css

I am working on a [site](http://www.dismantledesign.com/alpha) where there is a hover state for the gallery. I added an onclick to have the hover state appear when on the phone since there is no cursor.

When I shrink the browser on my laptop to see the responsive result, the links inside the hover states stay styled the way they are coded. When I load it on my phone, the text is larger than coded and the links are set to default styles.

Here is the code I have for those links. I have tried doing the code with and without the .gallery in front. Both times, mobile ignores the code for the small, h4 and a styles.

```
.gallery .captionheading {
  margin-top: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.galley .captionheading>h4>a {
  color: #fff;
}

.gallery .captionheading>h4>a:hover {
  color: #ffa901;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.gallery .captionheading>h4 {
  font-family: 'Unbuntu', Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.gallery .captionheading>small {
  font-family: 'Unbuntu', Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a media query targeting mobile resolutions which is overriding these styles?

Comment: Try clearing the cache on your phone, or open the site in a private window?

Comment: @dom_ahdigital - If there is, it's not in my css file. I also declared mine last so it would take priority.

Comment: I viewed your site on mobile and it appears the same as a resized browser

Comment: @sol - I tried your suggestion and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by your mobile browser having cached the CSS file.

Try clearing the cache, viewing the site in a private window, or viewing in a different browser.